# Contrary of almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

I am proving if $g \le f$ a.e and $\int_Xg=\int_Xf$, then $f=g$ a.e. I know there are several proof of this statement, but my main question is not this.

I can show

> *) if $g \le f$ on $X$ and $g<f$ on $E$ with $m(E)>0$, then $\int_X g <\int_X f$,

this can be achieved by the follows:

Construct $E=\cup E_n$ where $E_n:=\{x\in E: g(x)+\frac{1}{n}<f\}$ and find $E_{n_0}$ with $m(E_{n_0})>0$ by monotonicity of $E_n$. Therefore $g+\chi_{E_{n_0}}<f$ on $X$. By taking integral on both sides, we can easily see $\int_X g <\int_X f$.

I am wondering if it is true that the contrary of $f\le g $ a. is $\exists E$ with $m(E)>0$ such that $g<f$. If it is true, then $*)$ proves the proposition in the very beginning. If not, I am wondering if $*)$ is still useful for proving the proposition.

Comment: Your phrasing of the negation of "almost everywhere" in this case is correct.

Comment: What means a.m. ?

Comment: @EthanBolker But the negation of $f≤g$ a.m is $∀E$ with $m(E)=0, ∃x∈E^c$ such that $g(x)<f(x)$?. I am wondering, how I can construct a $m(E)>0$ such that $g<f$ on $E$

Comment: @LL3.14 $g\le f$ a.m means there exists $E$ with $m(E)=0$ such that $g\le f$ on $E^c$?

Comment: I was asking for the meaning in English ... Usually I only use a.e. for "almost everywhere" ... is a.m. the same as a.e. but for the measure m, or is m. For another word?

Comment: @LL3.14 sorry for that. It should be a.e. I will edit it.